# Yosida approximation, solution is $C^\infty$? (Explanation of passage needed)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces

I'm reading Brezis' book Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and PDEs, Lemma 7.1 page 186.

> Let $w \in C^1([0,\infty);H)$ satisfy
>   $$w' + A_{\lambda}w = 0$$
>   where $A_\lambda$ is the Yosida approximation to a maximal monotone operator $A$.
>
> Since $A_{\lambda}$ is linear and bounded, we deduce by induction from the above equation that $w \in C^\infty([0,\infty);H)$, and also that $w'$ also satisfies the above equation.

I don't understand this. Why is it true?

Comment: Example in the one-dimensional case: assume $y$ is solution of $y'+2y=0$. So $y$ is differentiable and $y'=-2y$ is differentiable, i.e. $y$ is twice differentiable, etc... Also, differentiating: $y''+2y'=0$, i.e. $z'+2z=0$ with $z=y'$. It works exactly the same in the bounded linear $H$-valued case.